# Where did my thought go wrong (electrical circuit )

Tags: voltage, diodes, current-measurement

The circuit on the right has two identical diodes, D1
and D2. These diodes have a scale factor n = 2 and a
value of saturation current IS = 9nA. The currents in
the diodes are as shown.

1. Use the ideal diode equation to calculate the diode
   voltages V1 and V2 and hence V3.
2. Using the above results, calculate the diode voltage drop with a current of I = 0.1mA without
   solving the ideal diode equation again. Explain what relationship you used

[image]

This was my steps to try to solve the question but my tutor thinks my answer was extremely wrong.

[image]

Comment: With handwriting like that you'd make a good doctor.

Comment: How did you derive V1 and V2? Show your working.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part I'm assuming 0.05 is Vt * n, which I suppose is close enough.  That part looks fine.

The second part is asking you to think about the fact that diode current has an exponential relationship.  So when the current is x times higher, the voltage is larger by an additive factor for any pair of currents (well above Is).  You found in the first part that 10 times the current increases the voltage by 0.115V.  So if you divide 1mA by 10 to get 0.1mA, you already know the difference between the new voltage and V2.

On a related note, there's a well known trick that Vt / 0.43 (or in this case Vt * n / 0.43) gives the voltage change per decade in current.  Technically it's actually Vt * ln(10).  For Vt = 25.9mV, that's works out to a well known 60mV/dec, or in this problem 0.1151V/dec.